# How to use nevertheless and nonetheless?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Are these examples correct?

> He was so weak **nevertheless** completed the task?
>
> The task was hard to complete but he is the man who **nonetheless** did that hard task.

My question is,

Are these words used as a replacement of the phrase "*in spite of*"?

Comment: Your first example is syntactic garbage, and the second is at the very least non-idiomatic.

Comment: Both *nevertheless* and *nonetheless* have the same *semantic* function as *in spite of*, but the syntactical rules are different. (You can use *in spite of*, but not without having to also rephrase the surrounding sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

No, neither one is correct English. The first one doesn't mean anything, though the second one can be understood.  However, none of the mistakes have to do with *none/nevertheless*, which is used correctly as an adverb in both examples.

The answer to the question

> Are these words used as a replacement of the phrase *in spite of*?

is No. They mean roughly the same thing as that phrase, but they are not replacements for it.

*Nonetheless* and *nevertheless* (which mean the same, incidentally) are always adverbs,
and may appear in many adverb niches:

- *Nevertheless, he passed the exam.* (comma optional)
- *He nevertheless passed the exam.*
- *He passed the exam nevertheless.*

Whereas *in spite of* (equivalent to *despite*, which falutes slightly higher) is a preposition,
and must appear with a noun phrase object.

- *He passed the exam, despite/in spite of his alarm clock.*
- *He passed the exam, despite/in spite of the weather.*
- *He passed the exam, despite/in spite of being malnourished.*

The entire prepositional phrase itself (including the object noun phrase) is a sentence adverbial,
and so it can be niched like an adverb

- *Despite/In spite of the weather, he passed the exam.*

But *in spite of* by itself can't be used as an adverb:

- **In spite of, he passed the exam.* (ungrammatical with or without comma)
- **He in spite of passed the exam.*
- **He passed the exam in spite of.*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help out the asker so carefully.